# Retrieving a list of agent requests from TFS REST API

Tags: tfs-2015, ms-release-management

TFS 2015.3, on premises.

The REST API of TFS has an undocumented portion that deals with app pools: `_apis/distributedtask/pools` on the server level and further down. I can drill down all the way to agent details: `_apis/distributedtask/pools/111/agents/222`. Now, in the Web UI there are two collections per agent: requests and capabilities. Does anyone know the REST API URLs for those? Adding either `/requests` or `/capabilities` yields a "Document not found" error.

If the TFS API is somehow self describing, I have yet to discover how. I miss WSDL...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I opened up Chrome Network inspector and found that these are the API calls for Requests and Capabilities. These are from latest VSTS but I think the same will work for TFS 2015.3 also.
[image]

For Requests:
`_apis/distributedtask/pools/1/jobrequests?agentId=1&completedRequestCount=25`

For Capabilities:
`_apis/distributedtask/pools/1/agents/1?includeCapabilities=true`

Note: These are undocumented so you should be vigilant while upgrading your TFS if you are taking dependencies on these.

Comment: Good to know that the TFS REST API calls that power the Web UI originate in the browser, not on the server. With that, and some version of Firebug, there's no limit.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot