# Get a list of builds/releases for an agent pool?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

Is there a way (via powershell, Azure DevOps' REST api, or via the UI) to pull a list of builds/releases run in the past X time on a specific Agent Pool?  I haven't found any documentation to indicate a method yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Get a list of builds/releases for an agent pool?

There is no such out-of-the-box API at this moment, because the agent REST API is undocumented, see [REST API Overview for Visual Studio Team Services and Team Foundation Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) for more information.

However you could use tools such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to track the the API, following below steps to get list of builds/releases for an agent pool with REST API:

1. Get Pool ID:

   `GET https://dev.azure.com/<YouOrganizationName>/_apis/distributedtask/pools/`

   [image]
2. Get Agent ID based on the pool ID:

   `GET https://dev.azure.com/<YouOrganizationName>/_apis/distributedtask/pools/5/agents/`

   [image]
3. Get the job requests the specific Build Agent:

   `GET https://dev.azure.com/<YouOrganizationName>/_apis/distributedtask/pools/5/jobrequests?agentId=4`

   [image]

Now, we could use scripts to list the those builds/releases info, like, "requestId",  "result" and so on.

The helped ticket: [Retrieving a list of agent requests from TFS REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050966/retrieving-a-list-of-agent-requests-from-tfs-rest-api)

Note:

> These are undocumented so you should be vigilant while upgrading your
>   TFS if you are taking dependencies on these.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll look into this and hopefully have a post on success/failure in a bit.  Far as I'm concerned though, this is a viable solution!

Comment: I've got this for the most part up and running, but now I'm digging around to find a way to link the job or request ID to some actual description of the job itself (name, pipeline).  The UI clearly shows the information, and I expected it to be in the list of jobs payload.  90% of the way there, thanks for getting me this far.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this "solved", as it gets close but not quite.  It still deserves an upvote, but until I can link job/request IDs to human-identifiable job information, this does nothing.

Comment: Found the last bit.  After reviewing the traffic I found a query to `https://[organization].visualstudio.com/[project]/_settings/agentqueues?queueId=[target queue]&__rt=fps&__ver=2`.  After dissecting its payload I found the needed identifying information.  If you want to add it to the post that's great, but now this qualifies as a full answer.  For those of you looking, it's best to use the above steps to get the identifying info for agents and their pools, but the job queue data can be found from a GET in this comment's link.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I couldn't find any mentions of `jobrequests` in Azure REST API doc. Could you please point it out?