# What does the query string completedRequestCount for the jobrequest endpoint return?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am calling the `jobrequest` endpoint of the [pools resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). Adding the querystring `completedRequestCount` returns a pattern I cannot figure out. (This api is undocumented).

`https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/jobrequests/?completedRequestCount={int}`

- If `{int}` is 0, then all running/unassigned jobs are returned
- If `{int}` is 1, then a number of results are returned. One pool returned two, another returned nine.
- If `{int}` is 2, then double the results of `{int}`=1 is returned. One pool returned four, another returned eighteen
- If `{int}` is 3, then three times the results of `{int}`=1 is returned

The returned jobs don't seem to be in a strict chronological order. The returned jobs are normally jobs that have been run recently.

What is the query string `completedRequestCount` returning and how does the changing of `{int}` affect it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to add `agentId` parameter in the request url ,the returned count shows normal, `completedRequestCount` parameter is used to specify the count of latest job requests returned. You can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050966/retrieving-a-list-of-agent-requests-from-tfs-rest-api).

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/jobrequests?agentId={agentId}&completedRequestCount={int}
```

Below is my test in postman :

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me realise that without the `agentId={agentId}` querystring, the endpoint returns the `completedRequestCount` for **each** agent in a pool. So if a pool has 4 agents `completedRequestCount=1` then four results are returned, the last completed request for each agent. If `completedRequestCount=2`, then 8 results are returned, the last two completed requests for each agent.

Answer (score 2):

Following from Hugh Lin's answer, I discovered that `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/jobrequests?completedRequestCount=1` returns the last completed job for **each** agent in the pool and are grouped by agent in chronological order.

The pool where I received 9 results when `?completedRequestCount=1`contained 9 agents, the pool where I received 2 results only had 2 agents.

When `completedRequestCount=2` then the last two completed jobs are returned for each agent.